# Finding and replacing numbers around ^'s in a file

Tags: bash

How can I search all instances of n^n, where n are numbers and replace this with $n^$? For e.g., `This morning, I ate 3^12 apples.` becomes `This morning, I ate $3^12$ apples.`; `Yesterday, I ate 12345^6789 carrots.` becomes `Yesterday, I ate $12345^6789$ carrots.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
echo This morning, I ate 3^12 apples. | sed "s/[0-9]\+^[0-9]\+/$&$/"
```

Outputs:

```
This morning, I ate $3^12$ apples.
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools like *sed* and *awk* make short work of problems like this.

Hints (in case this is homework):

- Use a substitute command for doing replacements:  http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1
- Use patterns to identify the replacement targets:  http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-27
- Use `\1` to keep parts of the pattern:  http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that sed would do this. I'm not personally experienced in using it, but it is an awesome program. If you want to learn it, [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) site seems to be a good guide.

Comment: If you don't have an actual answer to the question, leave a comment on the question instead (or, answer questions that you know so that you have enough reputation to leave a comment).